# Present while a presentation is in progress? Trying to display a new view after facebook login with parse.

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to present a UITableView I've already made for users to put in data and save in parse. I'm pretty sure I don't present the navigation view.

When I log in, I get the error:

```
Checklists[4516:c07] Warning: Attempt to present <ChecklistsViewController: 0x10525e90> 
on <UINavigationController: 0x9648270> while a presentation is in progress!
```

Thanks for your help.

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "ChecklistsViewController.h"
#import "SetupViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    PFLogInViewController *login = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
    login.fields = PFLogInFieldsFacebook;
    // Need to set the delegate to be this controller.
    login.delegate = self;
    login.signUpController.delegate = self; //signUpController is a property on the login view controller
    [self presentModalViewController:login animated:NO];

}

    - (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Successfully logged in.");
    ChecklistsViewController *controller = [[ChecklistsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UITableViewStylePlain;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This method has been deprecated for a good while

```
     presentModalViewController:animated:
```

You should use this instead

```
    presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

Same goes for this

```
    dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:
```

Now we use this

```
    dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
```

When we don't want a completion block, we just set it to nil.

But in your case, a completion block could fix your problem... it ensures a correct sequence of events, i.e. the presenting won't take place until the dismissing is complete.

```
    - (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController 
                   didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Successfully logged in.");
        ChecklistsViewController *controller = 
              [[ChecklistsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];

}
```

[NB - modalTransitionStyle was incorrect in your original code, I have changed that also. Thanks to [Daniel G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652402/daniel-g) for pointing this out]

Comment: Thanks! Very thorough. If you don't mind, I have one other error that just popped up after implementing your solution. "Warning: Attempt to present <ChecklistsViewController: 0xa4711c0> on <UINavigationController: 0xa28d750> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" Haven't seen this one.

Comment: @STANGMMX - I would need to know more about your app - what `UINavigationController` (or subclass)  would it be referring to? Perhaps raise another question showing a bit more information such as your storyboard, any other clues.. although one thing to try might be to move your code out of viewDidAppear - you have a confused situation as viewDidAppear is called whenever you dismiss your login screen. Or make a BOOL flag to ensure you don't try to re-present your login just after you have dismissed it.